# Compute $\iint_D(3x+3y)dA $ where $D =\{(x,y):−2\leq x\leq 2,\;0\leq y\leq \sqrt{4-x^2}\}$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute $\iint_D(3x+3y)dA $ where $D =\{(x,y):−2\leq x\leq 2,\;0\leq y\leq \sqrt{4-x^2}\}$.

I attempted it and got -8 as my answer, but this seems to be wrong.

What I did:

$$\begin{align}\iint_D(3x+3y)dA 
&=\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} (3x+3y) dydx\\
&=\int_{-2}^2[3(y^2)/2 ]_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} dx\\
&=\int_{-2}^2[3(4-x^2)]/2 dx\\
&=(3/2) \int_{-2}^2(4-x^2) dx\\
&=(3/2) [(-x^3)/3]_{-2}^2\\
&=(3/2) (-16/3)=-8.
\end{align}
$$
Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct, you just forgot the integral of $4$:
$$\frac{3}{2}\int_{-2}^24dx=24.$$
Hence the result should be $24-8=16$.

Comment: How silly of me. I was so used to integrating with 2 variables I just took 4 as 0 haha.